# Segmentation fault when changing value of attribute

Tags: c++11, raspberry-pi, polling

I'm working in a C++11 class that will fetch via I2C the value of a temperature sensor in a Raspberry Pi. It will be polling the value until it's stopped. It does the polling in a separate thread, so that it does not stop the application flow. The problem is that in the line 64 of this file: https://github.com/OpenStratos/server/blob/feature/temperature/temperature/Temperature.cpp#L64

```
void Temperature::read_temperature()
{
    while (this->reading)
    {
        #ifndef OS_TESTING
            int value = wiringPiI2CRead(this->filehandle);
        #else
            int value = 16000;
        #endif

        float voltage = value * 5 / 32768; // 2^15
        float temp = r_to_c(TEMP_R * (TEMP_VIN / voltage - 1));
        this->temperature = temp; // Gives segmentation fault

        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(50));
    }
}
```

it gives a segmentation fault. The curius thing is that it does not always happen. After compiling, running the binary many times about the 75% of the time will crash.

This is the file that invoques the code:https://github.com/OpenStratos/server/blob/feature/temperature/testing/temperature_test.cpp

```
Temperature temp(20);
temp.start_reading();
AssertThat(temp.is_reading(), Equals(true));

// this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100)); if uncommented less segmentation faults

temp.stop_reading();
AssertThat(temp.is_reading(), Equals(false));
```

What could be happening? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Please post the relevant code instead (or additionally to) the links. The links might go dead and it's much nicer to read if one can see what this is about.

Comment: I added the relevant code to the post :)

Comment: It seems like it might be possible for the `Temperature` instance to go out of scope while the thread is running. Your test might have to wait for the thread to exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for `Temperature::read_temperature()` to quit, so you need:

```
bool reading;
volatile bool stopped;  // volatile required to make the compiler re-read
                        // the value everytime we expect it to.
//
bool is_stopped(){ return stopped; }
```

and

```
void Temperature::start_reading()
{
    if (!reading)
    {
        stopped = false;
        reading = true;
        // etc
```

and

```
void Temperature::read_temperature()
{
    while (this->reading)
    {
    // etc
    }
    stopped=true;
}
```

and

```
temp.stop_reading();
while(!temp.is_stopped();  
AssertThat(temp.is_reading(), Equals(false));
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of it. But I have a new problem, the scripts enters in an infinite loop in the `while(!temp.is_stopped();` it does not happen if I change it to `while(!temp.is_stopped(){this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));};`. Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm not yet an expert with `C++11`, but you could try changing stopped to `volatile bool stopped;`, or `std::atomic<bool> stopped;`.  See what happens.

Comment: Perfect! volatile keyword made the trick. The while() was not checking the value in each iteration, since the compiler treated it as if it was not changing in the code, but the other thread was changing it. Thanks a lot!